# Why does ws.run_forever() return True instead of the api values in this case?

Tags: python, websocket, binance, cryptocurrency, binance-api-client

I'm trying to get the klines value of BTC-USDT from binance but I can't seem to fetch the right values

```
def on_message(ws, message):
    print("received a message")
    print(json.loads(message))     

def on_close(ws):
    print("closed connection")        

def on_open(ws):
    print("opened")


ws = websocket.WebSocketApp('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=BTCUSDT&interval=1s', on_open=on_open,on_message=on_message, on_close=on_close)
ws.run_forever()
```

Why does ws.run_forever() return True instead of the values?

Comment: What values do you mean?

Comment: @kindall the candlestick values,  also,the interval is 1m not 1s

Comment: How could it return any of those values? They haven't been received yet. (And you don't save the values in any of your event handlers either.)

Comment: @kindall so, I'm running this on google colab rn and I was watching a video to go with it. I thought ws.run_forever() would return a live, infinitely long,constantly updating list of values from the website? Sorry if I sound dumb, I'm new to APIs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The websocket api base url is `wss://stream.binance.com:9443`, not the http/rest api url. That's why you didn't receive anything from websocket.

Also `run_forever()` will just block without return anything. The "value" you need will be given as an argument of `on_message`.

```
def on_message(ws, message):
     print("received a message:")
     print(json.loads(message))

def on_close(ws):
     print("closed connection")

def on_open(ws):
     print("opened")
    
    
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp('wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@kline_1m', on_open=on_open,on_message=on_message, on_close=on_close)
# please check binance document to write the correct stream name
ws.run_forever()
```

Or, if you need some information not as a stream:

```
# REST API example

import httpx
resp = httpx.get('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=BTCUSDT&interval=1m&limit=1')
print(resp.json())
```